# Node opcua crawler method and ua expert results are different

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

Opcua node crawler method giving me an array of 745 items. But I can only see around 25 items when I look at ua expert.

My current code:

```js
const client = opcua.OPCUAClient.create(connectionOption);
await client.connect(url);
const session = await client.createSession(userIdentity);
const items = [];
var crawler = new NodeCrawler(session);
crawler.on("browsed", function (element) {
   if (element.nodeClass === 2) {// 2 means variable type
       const nodeId = new opcua.NodeId(element.nodeId.identifierType, element.nodeId.value, element.nodeId.namespace);
       const nodeIdString = nodeId.toString();
       items.push(nodeIdString);
    }
});
await crawler.read(nodeId);
```

How can I get the same result as UaExpert?

My code result:

[image]

UaExpert:

[image]

Nodes which are not shown in UaExpert but exits in crawler result:

[image]

Node details which is not shown in UaExpert

```js
{
    description: null,
    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11574',
    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
    references: [
        {
            referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=37',
            isForward: true,
            nodeId: 'ns=0;i=80',
            browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'Optional' },
            displayName: { text: 'Optional' },
            nodeClass: 'Object',
            typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=77',
        },
        {
            referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=40',
            isForward: true,
            nodeId: 'ns=0;i=68',
            browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'PropertyType' },
            displayName: { text: 'PropertyType' },
            nodeClass: 'VariableType',
            typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
        },
    ],
    nodeClass: 2,
    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
    displayName: { text: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
    parent: {
        description: null,
        nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11564',
        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'OperationLimitsType' },
        references: [
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11574',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11570',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerBrowse' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerBrowse' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=12161',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryReadData' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryReadData' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=12162',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryReadEvents' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryReadEvents' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=12163',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateData' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateData' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=12164',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateEvents' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateEvents' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11569',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerMethodCall' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerMethodCall' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11573',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerNodeManagement' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerNodeManagement' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11565',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerRead' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerRead' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11571',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerRegisterNodes' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerRegisterNodes' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11572',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerTranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerTranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
            {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11567',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxNodesPerWrite' },
                displayName: { text: 'MaxNodesPerWrite' },
                nodeClass: 'Variable',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
            },
        ],
        nodeClass: 8,
        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
        displayName: { text: 'OperationLimitsType' },
        parent: {
            description: null,
            nodeId: 'ns=0;i=61',
            browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'FolderType' },
            references: [
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=16405',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'AlarmGroupType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'AlarmGroupType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=23456',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'AliasNameCategoryType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'AliasNameCategoryType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=23556',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'AuthorizationServicesConfigurationFolderType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'AuthorizationServicesConfigurationFolderType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=13813',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'CertificateGroupFolderType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'CertificateGroupFolderType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=17591',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'DictionaryFolderType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'DictionaryFolderType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=13353',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'FileDirectoryType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'FileDirectoryType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=17496',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'KeyCredentialConfigurationFolderType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'KeyCredentialConfigurationFolderType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11564',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'OperationLimitsType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'OperationLimitsType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
                {
                    referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
                    isForward: true,
                    nodeId: 'ns=2;i=1005',
                    browseName: { namespaceIndex: 2, name: 'FunctionalGroupType' },
                    displayName: { text: 'FunctionalGroupType' },
                    nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                    typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                },
            ],
            typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
            displayName: { text: 'FolderType' },
            parent: {
                description: null,
                nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Scalar' },
                references: [
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=40',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=0;i=61',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'FolderType' },
                        displayName: { text: 'FolderType' },
                        nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Boolean',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Boolean' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Boolean' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Byte',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Byte' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Byte' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.ByteString',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'ByteString' },
                        displayName: { text: 'ByteString' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.DateTime',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'DateTime' },
                        displayName: { text: 'DateTime' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Double',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Double' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Double' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.ExpandedNodeId',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'ExpandedNodeId' },
                        displayName: { text: 'ExpandedNodeId' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Float',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Float' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Float' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Guid',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Guid' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Guid' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.ImageGIF',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'ImageGIF' },
                        displayName: { text: 'ImageGIF' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Int16',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Int16' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Int16' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Int32',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Int32' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Int32' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Int64',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Int64' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Int64' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.LocalizedText',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'LocalizedText' },
                        displayName: { text: 'LocalizedText' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.NodeId',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'NodeId' },
                        displayName: { text: 'NodeId' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.QualifiedName',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'QualifiedName' },
                        displayName: { text: 'QualifiedName' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Quality_DynamicValue',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Quality_DynamicValue' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Quality_DynamicValue' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Quality_StaticValue',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'Quality_StaticValue' },
                        displayName: { text: 'Quality_StaticValue' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.SByte',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'SByte' },
                        displayName: { text: 'SByte' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.StatusCode',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'StatusCode' },
                        displayName: { text: 'StatusCode' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.String',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'String' },
                        displayName: { text: 'String' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.UInt16',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'UInt16' },
                        displayName: { text: 'UInt16' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.UInt32',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'UInt32' },
                        displayName: { text: 'UInt32' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.UInt64',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'UInt64' },
                        displayName: { text: 'UInt64' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                    {
                        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=35',
                        isForward: true,
                        nodeId: 'ns=4;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.XmlElement',
                        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 4, name: 'XmlElement' },
                        displayName: { text: 'XmlElement' },
                        nodeClass: 'Variable',
                        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=63',
                    },
                ],
                nodeClass: 1,
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=61',
                displayName: { text: 'Scalar' },
            },
            referenceToParent: {
                referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=40',
                isForward: true,
                nodeId: 'ns=0;i=61',
                browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'FolderType' },
                displayName: { text: 'FolderType' },
                nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
                typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
            },
        },
        referenceToParent: {
            referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=45',
            isForward: true,
            nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11564',
            browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'OperationLimitsType' },
            displayName: { text: 'OperationLimitsType' },
            nodeClass: 'ObjectType',
            typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=0',
        },
    },
    referenceToParent: {
        referenceTypeId: 'ns=0;i=46',
        isForward: true,
        nodeId: 'ns=0;i=11574',
        browseName: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
        displayName: { text: 'MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall' },
        nodeClass: 'Variable',
        typeDefinition: 'ns=0;i=68',
    },
    dataType: 'ns=0;i=7',
    dataValue: {
        value: { dataType: 'Null', arrayType: 'Scalar' },
        statusCode: { value: 0 },
        sourceTimestamp: '2022-12-29T15:48:59.598Z',
        sourcePicoseconds: 801300000,
        serverTimestamp: '2022-12-29T15:48:59.598Z',
        serverPicoseconds: 801300000,
    },
    valueRank: -1,
    minimumSamplingInterval: 50,
    accessLevel: 1,
    userAccessLevel: 1,
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually enter the address of one of the "missing" nodes into UaExpert to see if it can read the node?  It may be possible that the node does not have correct Browse permissions or is orphaned but it is still there.

Comment: Where can I enter the address manually, I could not find. I'm using the 1.6.3v of ua expert.

Comment: Right-click on the Data Access View in the middle and select Add custom node... You can enter the address there.

Comment: I added a new ss, I'm not sure what they are, is there a way to filter them from crawler?

Comment: The last image you have shows nodes with a numeric address (i=11574).  What creates those nodes?  What sets their access permissions?  Based on the name, looks like they are meta nodes created by the OPCUA server.

Comment: Can you get the crawler to print out the address on each node?

Comment: I do not know what created these nodes, I'm using local plc simulator maybe it is creating them automatically, I added the whole info that I can access from crawler.

Comment: Can you have the crawler print out the address of the nodes?  With that, you should be able to see them in UaExpert.  What PLC simulator are you using?  It may be possible that it is not setting the Browse permissions on the auto-generated nodes.

Comment: Okay I found a way to filter them, all of the nodes I do not want to see have accessLevel:1. So now I'm able to filter them from result by simply changing this line `(element.nodeClass === 2)` to this `(element.nodeClass === 2 && element.accessLevel === 3)`, thank you for your help.

Comment: Great job.  I suggest you write an answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the results, you can do it by accessLevel attribute. In my case all of the nodes I want to see in crawler result have accessLevel:3.

Simply changing this line

from `(element.nodeClass === 2)`

to `(element.nodeClass === 2 && element.accessLevel === 3)`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the nodes in youe json are (sub-)part of the server Object.
So I think you browse the complett nodeset and not only the Scalar folder.